# Find all solutions to $\sin(x+3)=\sin3x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all solutions to $\sin(x+3)=\sin3x$

I am trying to find real solutions. Do I need to solve $x+3=3x$?

Comment: Or, $x+3 = 3x + 2n\pi$ , where $n=0,1,2,3,...$

Comment: @rapidracim There are other solutions

Answer (score 2):

Note that in general

> $$\sin \alpha=\sin \beta \iff \alpha=\beta+2k\pi \quad \lor \quad \alpha=\pi-\beta+2k\pi$$

then

$$\sin(x+3)=\sin3x \iff x+3=3x+2k\pi \quad \lor \quad x+3=\pi-3x+2k\pi$$

and thus

$$\begin{cases}x+3=3x+2k\pi \implies x=\frac32+k\pi\\\\x+3=\pi-3x+2k\pi\implies x=\frac{\pi-3}4+k\frac{\pi}2\end{cases}$$

Comment: Gimusi. I get x= 3/2 (+-) kπ, first equation, should it read kπ instead  of your 2kπ?:))Regards.

Comment: @PeterSzilas of course you are right, I didn't divide by 2! Thanks a lot, I fix

Comment: Gimusi.Congratulations you passed 20/. Super! As long as you enjoy it. I enjoy reading many of your solutions.:)))

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks Peter for you rappreciation, I Always happy to read your solutions here! Anyway I need 25 rep points more to reach 20k :)

Answer (score 1):

Option:

$\sin A -\sin B = $

$2(\sin(A-B)/2)(\cos(A+B)/2)= 0.$

Find the zeroes of $\sin(A-B)/2$ , and

of $ \cos(A+B)/2.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT...you have $$x+3=3x+k.2\pi$$ **or** $$x+3=\pi-3x+k.2\pi$$

Comment: Why are you adding 2πk and why    π-3x+2kπ